# print the strings such that those which are permutations of one another are printed together in java

Tags: java, string, sorting

I am trying to implement if you have a continuous stream of strings. At any point of time, you have to print the strings such that those which are permutations of one another are printed together.

For example:

```
Input: {‘act’,’cat’,dog’,’tac’,’abc’,’god’,’bac’}

Output: {‘act’,’cat’ ,’tac’,dog’,’god’,’abc’,’bac’}
```

I have written code for this where I am sorting each and every string. How to proceed further in this code.?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StringAnonmous {
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    String[] wordArr = {"cat", "dog", "tac", "god", "act"};
    String[] clonedArr=wordArr.clone();

    for(int i=0;i<wordArr.length;i++){
        String word=wordArr[i];
        char[] singleword=word.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(singleword);
        System.out.println(singleword);

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual permutation will take too long. For each string, an array of 26 counts can be used, where each count is the number of instances of a letter in the string, assuming all strings only contain lower case letters. If the strings can be any character, then use an array of 256 counts. This would allow for a quick comparison of counts to see if two strings are just permutations.

You'd need some reasonably fast way to search / insert an array of counts into some type of collection, perhaps a map. You'd also need some type of identifier for each string, like an index, and some type of collection that would allow you to note which strings are permutations of each other.

Assuming a map is used, if there's no default comparartor for an array of integers, you'll have to create one. The key would be an array of counts, and the value the index of a string. Each time you do a put(key, value), it will return null or index of the prior string that has the same key.

So now that you have a way to check if a string is a permutation of a prior string, see if you can figure out a way to store this information (unique strings versus strings that are permutations).

Comment: Can you please suggest one/

Comment: @JavaDevelopers - Assuming this is homework, I can only offer suggestions. I updated my answer to show how a map could be used to check for "matches" of strings.